# Multiple commands produce - Command ProcessXCFramework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

My current iOS 13+ (xcode 12.5) simplified project setup has some nested dependencies as follows:

```
Alamofire.xcframework -- is linked into ->  Internal-Framework-A
Alamofire.xcframework -- is linked into ->  Internal-Framework-B

Internal-Framework-A -- is linked into -> AppTarget (actual application target)
Internal-Framework-B -- is linked into -> AppTarget
```

Because Alamofire.xcframework is being linked into multiple internal frameworks, it will be linked without actual embedding.
This means that AppTarget will need to link and embed Alamofire.xcframework so that the internal frameworks can dynamically link it at runtime.

Internal frameworks compile correctly with this setup but AppTarget doesn't compile and it's trowing the follow error:
**Multiple commands produce ... Command: ProcessXCFramework**
and the reason for that being:

- on compile time AppTarget compiles Internal-Framework-A that triggers the ProcessXCFramework for Alamofire.xcframework but because AppTarget also has Alamofire.xcframework as dependency it will also run the ProcessXCFramework command, so we will have 2 commands for the same file.

I'm curious to know if there is something that I'm missing. It would look like there should be a flag for xcode to process the same framework once.

Comment: hey buddy, did you find any resolution to that? I am facing the same problem

Comment: dont really solve it but if I remove the sign team it works fine